# Submitted app does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have a question.
I've written a application for iOS, but I have a problem when I try to submit my application to the App Store.

> From Apple:
>   "*On launch and content download, your app stores 252.95MB, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.*"

How can I solve it?

I want to keep all the data. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Try to remove unused images from bundle may be that will reduce the bundle size

Comment: what resolution images you are using ?

Comment: Store the data in the caches folder instead of the documents folder.

Comment: Hi rmaddy!
Can you instruct detail for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your document path to cache folder

Answer (score 1):

iOS apps can be as large as 2 GB, but the executable file cannot exceed 60 MB.

Other files, like image, video, and audio can total up to 2GB of size.

Refer to this question: [Maximum size for iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646205/maximum-size-for-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

you are storing 252.95MB in the app document directory on running the application first time. Review your app and check why you need to store that amount of data. If you still need to download that amount of data because of requirement than contact Apple regarding the same with a proper reason.