# What should be the limit of an IPA file size for successfully review on apple store?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, submission

My App size is 308.5 MB on disk , the IPA size also almost same , As of the Apple store submission rules , Is this size make any issue?

Comment: what have you used that makes it 308 MB? I think there is limit...

Comment: there is 2GB limitation. if files is more than 100 MB you will get warning that requires WIFI to download it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646205/maximum-size-for-ios-app this link is similar to your question.

Comment: [here is your answer - 4GB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4753253/1066828)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application) :

4GB's is the maximum size your iOS app can be.

As of January 26, 2017

> App Size for iOS (& tvOS) only
>
> Your app’s total uncompressed size must be less than 4GB. Each Mach-O
>   executable file (for example, app_name.app/app_name) must not exceed
>   these limits:
>
> For apps whose MinimumOSVersion is less than 7.0: maximum of 80 MB for
>   the total of all __TEXT sections in the binary. For apps whose
>   MinimumOSVersion is 7.x through 8.x: maximum of 60 MB per slice for
>   the __TEXT section of each architecture slice in the binary. For apps
>   whose MinimumOSVersion is 9.0 or greater: maximum of 500 MB for the
>   total of all  __TEXT sections in the binary. However, consider
>   download times when determining your app’s size. Minimize the file’s
>   size as much as possible, keeping in mind that there is a 100 MB limit
>   for over-the-air downloads.

[This information can be found at iTunes Connect Developer Guide: Submitting the App to App Review.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html)

Comment: __TEXT sections in the binary means? Need to make Target device 9.0 and above !

Comment: i couldn't find what __TEXT sections mean but for the best hope make your minimum OS 9.0 to be safe

Comment: from my search i think it's memory usage 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/VMPages.html